# Does boost support circular files?

Tags: c++, linux, file, logging, boost

I need to use a circular file to keep a large amount of dynamic data (write-once, probably never read) on disk.

To be more clear, I want to treat a file as a circular buffer - i.e. writes to the buffer will go to the file, and reads will be file reads. Specifically I'm doing logs.

I was wondering if boost has any functionality that I can use (ideally a circular file).

I saw there is a circular buffer in boost, but I can't use it with a file as some sort of back-end. I have even thought about `mmap()`-ing the file into memory (which will not be a good solution if I use logs with more than 4GBs in size), and returning the mapped chunk back from the `Allocator` that I will pass to the buffer.
This seems to be a bad approach since the circular buffer documentation says that `Allocator` will be used for **any** memory allocation (and not just the buffer allocation).

Is there any other functionality for circular files, or some other way to do this?

Well, I actually meant logging in the sense of file-system logs (that is logging writes). I have a disk that I want to log (the writes to it) so that I can do CDP. I need to keep a log of all the writes, and of the marks so that I can roll the disk back to a position it was at earlier.
The logs may have a lot of space (over 10GB easily), so I don't know if the mmap solution would work.

Comment: If log entries are of a fixed length then a Random Access file? r+ mode - fseek?

Answer (score 6):

How about using Boost's Circular Buffer + Boost IPC's memory mapped file? The IPC documentation says its possible: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html (see the last line).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how it would work, but I think I need to map all the memory I want. Assuming boost uses usual mmap semantics (mapping virtual memory), it would be very wasteful to map more than a couple of 100's of megabytes. Since I'm talking about disk logging, the user can easily ask for a 5GB log (win system restore is 10% of disk size for instance), so I'm not sure if this is the right way for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) acceptable? It's in C, rather than C++, but hopefully building an object-oriented shim around the API wouldn't be too awful.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it is a good library, but I've already started using boost, and I don't want to use another library (it would probably take time to get the hang of it, and also it would mean one more thing to install when using the application). I believe it would be easier to just write it myself than actually use a library just for that.

Comment: @TomM, completely understood. :) But most distributions already ship with RRDTool, so it's just adding one more dependency line to your `Packages.gz` file and `foo.spec` file.

Comment: Actually, that's a great thing, and it made me reconsider. But after looking at the RRDtool website I think there would be a significant learning period which I don't want to pay :)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question as Linux, and you are writing log files, so configure [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for your application. It is more than flexible enough to do what you want.